# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" when running "ga.nlp.annotate" using GraphAware NLP

Tags: neo4j

Windows 10
32Gb RAM
8 core Xeon processor at 3.4GHz

```
Neo4j 3.4.7
Neo4j Browser 3.2.13
apoc-3.4.0.3.jar
graphaware-nlp-3.4.7.52.13.jar
graphaware-server-community-all-3.4.7.52.jar
nlp-stanfordnlp-3.4.7.52.13.jar
stanford-english-corenlp-2018-10-05-models.jar
```

Hi. I am trying to annotate all the text fields in my database. There are 25532 nodes with text values.

I'm using the following query to do this:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate(
"MATCH (n:FreeTextResponse) WHERE NOT (n)-[:HAS_ANNOTATED_TEXT]->() RETURN n",
"CALL ga.nlp.annotate({text: n.fullSentenceString, id: id(n), checkLanguage: false})
YIELD result MERGE (n)-[:HAS_ANNOTATED_TEXT]->(result)", {batchSize:1, iterateList:false})
```

...and am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I'm sure this is just a settings change somewhere, but I'm not sure what or where. Sorry if this is a bit of a newbie question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default configuration is 512MB and it is not enough for the models used by Stanford NLP. 
As suggested here:

https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-nlp

Change your neo4j.conf file in the following way:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=3000m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=5000m
```

Although considering your RAM availability I would suggest 5GB for both values.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Greatly appreciated.  That seems to have done the trick.  I am currently processing the co-sine similarity having successfully processed the annotations.  Annotations processed in about 5 hours creating around 21 000 Annotated text nodes.  I set the similarity running and it's still running 17 hours later.  It's using 100% of the CPU capacity.  Does that sound normal to you?  Thanks very much indeed!

Comment: yes it is normal. In the Enterprise Edition we are developing optimization fro cosine similarity computation. Consider that in the "basic" version it is computing 21000x21000 similarities. Even though we improved it quite a lot it is a huge number of computation.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know.  I'll just cross my fingers and hope it completes without issues then :)  Any idea how long I might expect it to take, or is that a how long is a piece of string question?  It's a great plugin by the way!  Thank you.

Comment: Just following this question up @Allessandro as my UPS is having problems and I am unsure whether to kill the query or leave it running.  Project deadline has now passed and it's been running for 58 hours.  Is there any way to 1) know how long the query will take / how far through it is or 2) stop the query, restart the computer and continue it where it left off? Thanks!

Comment: in the neo4j log there should be something useful to understand what’s going on

Comment: Thanks. That's helpful. So it's saying that 2 850 000 relationships have been computed.  By my maths the total number of relationships that requires computing is 25532*25532=651 883 024.  I calculate from this that the number of days that it would take to complete at this rate (49138 calculations per hour) that would take 550 days to complete.  Does that sound plausible or am I way off?  If so is there any other way of doing this as clearly that's infeasible. Thanks again.

Comment: your computation is correct, it seems to me that it is quite slow. send us an email at nlp (at) graphaware.com so we can get in touch and see how we can help. I need more details about the scenario.

Comment: Will do. In the meantime can I turn off my machine so that I can sort the ups without loosing data? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you.  Emailing now.  Much appreciated.

Comment: I've emailed as much info as I can.  Would it make any difference that I used the "Microsoft Concept Graph" rather than the "ConceptNet5" enricher?